# Problem executing a script in Bash linked to another script that creates a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

First of all, thanks in advance. I'm new to BASH and I would need help with two scripts that I have created. I have dataset downloaded from GITHUB on Covid cases by country. I don't know what the problem is but I can't run correctly a 'B' script that runs after another 'A' script which creates a csv file.

I share the code that I am using.

Script 'A.sh' (sure that the code is very improvable)

```
#!/bin/bash

# transpose dates
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};NR==1{n = split($0,a); print "Country,date,value"; next};{for(i=2;i<NF;i++) print $1,a[i],$i}' $HOME/casos_covid.csv |

# We carried out a Groupby because there are countries that in the original dataset had a detail of covid cases by province / region. 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};NR==1{print;next};{a[$1","$2]+=$3};END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' > $HOME/data.csv
```

Script 'B.sh' links through a main script that runs both scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Vlookup between the countries file and the dataset data.csv 
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next};NR>1{if($1 in a){print $2,$3,a[$1]}}' $HOME/paises_ok.csv $HOME/data.csv |

# Rearrange the dataset
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};{print $3,$1,$2}' |

# Groupby Continent. Sum the cases by continent.
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","};NR==1{print;next};{a[$1","$2]+=$3};END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' > cases_continent.csv
```

I also attach the main.sh script that I have created.

```
#!/bin/bash
$HOME/A.sh |
$HOME/B.sh
```

it doesn't work the first 'awk' command from the B.sh script where I do a Vlookup with another file that contains a list of countries and continents. I always get the same result ... the data.csv file is generated (script A) but then the script code B.sh runs to the end and generates the file 'cases_continent.csv' but generates it empty. It's like it doesn't read the data.csv file generated in the A.sh script.

I don't understand it and I would greatly appreciate your help and know where I am going wrong.

Thanks again,

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand, but it looks like main.sh should *not* use a pipe to connect the two scripts -- you want to run B.sh after A.sh, but a pipe runs both at once with standard output of the first connected to standard input of the second.

Comment: You also don't need `source`, just call the 2 commands - `$HOME/A.sh && $HOME/B.sh`. If it's still not working then just execute the 3 awk scripts from B.sh one at a time to identify and then debug which one fails.

Comment: Also consider using a better language for parsing CSV data. You would have problems with quoted fields.

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @Gordon Davisson. The problem was the plumbing. Now the main script works perfectly.

Comment: It's true @Ed Morton, thanks for you comment. I have already edited it and changed it